# Parse date based on locale using simpledateformatter

Tags: java, date

I am getting the date in long format like this :
Wednesday, August 1, 2018

I want this in the below format:
Wed, Aug 01, 2018

I used the below code:

```
public static String getShortDate(Date date){
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd, yyyy");
            return format.format(date);
}
```

This works fine for en_US. But how to make it work for other locales

For example the long format for German is :
    Samstag, 16. Juni 2018
how to get the above short format for it?
The getShortDate method parameter takes Date, but I can change it to String.

If the longer format is : Samstag, 16. Juni 2018
i need it to be :  Sa., 16. Jun. 2018

i am using the below code :

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM, yyyy", locale);
            return format.format(date);
```

This is giving me output as: Sa, 16 Jun, 2018
How to get that dot(.) after Sa

Answer (score 1):

To get short date format in different locale code, you could try below code:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =
                new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd, yyyy", new Locale("de", "de"));//for german germany
        String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
```

**Output:**

> Di, Mär 27, 2018

Comment: Or you can say `Locale.GERMAN` instead of creating new locale object